# DateTime('now') not modified after sleep()

Tags: php, datetime

I have following code

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$string1 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
sleep(5);
$now->modify('now');        
$string2 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
sleep(10);
$now->modify('now');        
$string3 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $string1 . '<br>';
echo $string2 . '<br>';
echo $string3 . '<br>';
```

I expected to get each line different time. surprisingly the output is like this.

```
2020-11-27 17:35:05
2020-11-27 17:35:05
2020-11-27 17:35:05
```

I suspected it is the buffer flush problem so added `$string` variables but it is still the same. Can anyone explain why it happens? Thanks.

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'now' parameter is simply ignored. This is also documented in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).
When creating with

```
$now = date_create(); // or new DateTime;
```

It doesn't matter whether the parameter is "now" or none.

My recommendation: Always recreate the current time with new DateTime.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. This is strange, a wanted to avoid creation of thousands of objects, every couple of seconds just to log something with the new date in proper timezone..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) for this, like so:

```
<?php

$now = new DateTime('now');
$string1 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
sleep(5);
// DateInterval accepts a formatted period specifier:
// P = Period
// T = Time
// 5 = 5 units
// S = Seconds
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT5S'));
$string2 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
sleep(10);
$now->add(new DateInterval('PT10S'));
$string3 = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $string1 . '<br>';
echo $string2 . '<br>';
echo $string3 . '<br>';
```

Comment: I don't know what the intervals will be. This is why I wanted to modify to 'now'. jspit answer did the trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're `sleep()`ing intermittently, then surely you must be able to pass the same interval to the period specifier? If you want to avoid instantiating a bunch of additional `DateTime`s, then this will help you do that.